# Regularised Logistic regression in Python[numpy] giving wrong results

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I'm trying to program a logistic regression using python and numpy(with dataset generation from `sklearn.datasets`). The code is give below:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as la

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1.0/(np.exp(-x) + 1)

def Cost(X,y,w,Lambda):
    #return regularised least squares cost function
    m = y.size
    cost = -sum(y*(np.log(sigmoid(np.dot(X,w)))) + (1-y)*(np.log(1-sigmoid(np.dot(X,w)))))/(m) + Lambda*sum(w[1:].T.dot(w[1:]))/(2*m);
    return cost[0]

def gradient(X,y,w,Lambda):
    #return gradient vector of cost function
    m = y.size
    grad = ((X.T).dot(sigmoid(X.dot(w) - y)))/m + Lambda*w/m
    grad[0] = grad[0] - Lambda*w[0]/m
    return grad

def gd(X,y,w,alpha,num_iters,Lambda):
    #perform gradient descent
    Cost_history = np.zeros((num_iters,1))
    for i in range(num_iters):
        Cost_history[i] = Cost(X,y,w,Lambda)
        w = w - alpha*gradient(X,y,w,Lambda)
    return w, Cost_history

def sgd(X,y,w,alpha,num_iters,Lambda):
    pass

def fit(X,y,Lambda=None,alpha=None,num_iters=None):
    if Lambda == None:
        Lambda = 0;
    if alpha == None:
        alpha = 0.03
    if num_iters == None:
        num_iters = 50
    m = X.shape[0]
    D = X.size//X.shape[0]
    X = np.c_[np.ones((m,1)),X]
    #w = np.random.rand(D,1)
    w = np.zeros((D+1,1))
    #w = np.r_[(np.arange(1)+1).reshape(1,1),w]
    w, Cost_history = gd(X,y,w,alpha,num_iters,Lambda)
    return w, Cost_history

def predict(X,w):
    m = X.shape[0]
    X = np.c_[np.ones((m,1)), X]
    y = X.dot(w)
    for i in range(m):
        if y[i]>=0:
            y[i] = 1
        else:
            y[i] = 0

    return y
```

The script I'm using to generate the dataset is:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
X, y = make_blobs(n_features=2, centers=2)
y = y.reshape(y.size,1)
```

and the training is done by:

```
w, cost_history = fit(X,y,alpha=0.001,num_iters=1000)
```

The decision boundary plot looks like:

[image: Decision boundary and the 2 classes' scatterplot]

The cost_history plot looks like this(vs epochs):
[image: J vs epochs]

Why is it so? Because the cost functions seem to be correct and so are the gradient functions and I cant seem to figure out why the cost is diverging, whereas the same code modified for linear regression with regularization works fine.

The plot code is:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1],marker='o',c=y)
plt.plot(linspace(-10,10),-w[0]/w[2] + w[1]*linspace(-10,10)/w[2],'k-')
plt.show()
```

[Basically I'm just a learner and I am trying to make a small mini library of ML techniques from scratch to get a feel. Am I doing it right? Or do I just use basic tools from sklearn and the proceed from there to learn more complex things? Also, sorry for the poor structured question, as I am just a beginner.]

Comment: So are you saying that when you add regularization and even though you by default don't set a parameter for it (`Lambda` in your case), the decision boundary doesn't converge compared to your original implementation without regularization? I don't see anything wrong with your code. It looks correct.

Comment: rayreng No, I actually said that this same code(with modifications in cost function and gradient, obviously) for LINEAR regression works fine. I suspected that the implementation of cost function might have to do something with the wrong answers but on a fresh look I realised my mistake_ it was a deceptively simple mistake of a paranthesis closing after y in grad function(talk about a code smell!). Well anyway, thanks a lot for your insight and the editing!

Comment: Oh wow lol. Yeah I ran the code. The parameters were learning fine but the cost function was wrong. Haven't had the time to comment but that was it. Glad you found it. Good luck!